# How can I add a new DB row and then edit it using a GridView control?

Tags: .net, gridview

In my application I am using a grid view control.

I am creating a new empty row in my grid view control using the following code:

```
string co = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyLogin"];
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(co);
            connection.Open();                
string sql = "insert into TeamMember_table "
          + "values('','','','','','','','','','','','')";                
SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);                
DataSet ds = new DataSet();                
dp.Fill(ds);                
gridview1.DataBind();               
connection.Close();
```

The empty row was added successfully, but my problem is I want to enter values into this empty row and save this value to a table when I click my save button.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to a `SqlDataAdapter` is the `SELECT` statement to use; your code is adding a new database row every time the data is queried (which sounds very, very wrong), plus I anticipate the query itself won't really work due to the confusion over the `INSERT` vs `SELECT`.

You should really just be doing a `SELECT` from `TeamMember_table`, and then *perhaps* adding a row the the *local* data-table afterwards:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM TeamMember_table";
SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);                
DataSet ds = new DataSet();   
dp.Fill(ds);
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
table.Rows.Add("", "", ..., "")
```

Personally, I *wouldn't* add a fake row unless it was absolutely essential to the binding; I can't advise on that, I'm afraid... but you'll need to be careful that you don't add empty rows accidentally. Perhaps check on the post-back (assuming ASP.NET), and only save if it has something useful in it.

Comment: i am the beginner for .net ur code is to create a empty row.but i am also asking to save the data which is in newly created row pls help

Comment: ASP.NET binding is not my speciality, I'm afraid. I'd use discreet INSERT calls to add the data (either via an SP, ov via ORM), but this would be lengthy to describe...

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use events like RowDataBoudn and RowDataDelete to impliment these behaviors. For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GridView1.RowDataBound += GridView1_RowDataBound;
    GridView1.RowUpdated += GridView1_RowUpdated;
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        string co = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"];
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(co)) {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "select ....";
            SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dp.Fill(ds);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["MyTable"];
            GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Id" };
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }                
    }
}

void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        Label l = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
        l.Text = "some text value";
    }
}
```